# Django get duration between now and DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, date

I have a Django model with the following field:

```
date = models.DateTimeField('start date')
```

I want to create a duration function that returns the duration between now and the date in the format "hours:minutes"

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```py
from django.utils import timezone


class Foo(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def duration(self):
        _seconds = (timezone.now() - self.date).total_seconds()
        _hours = int(_seconds / 3600)
        _minutes = int((_seconds % 3600) / 60)
        return f"{_hours}:{_minutes}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! I've tuned the return with : `return f"{_hours}:{_minutes:02d}"` to force two digits for the minutes